# In tidymodel autoplot getting error: Error in pset$object[[which(pset$id == x_col)]] : attempt to select less than one element in get1index

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidymodels

I am new to `tidymodels` & was trying code from **David Robinson Sliced Customer Churn episode** but getting some errors.

**Issue:** When I try to do `autoplot()` after creating a model then I get this error:

> Error in pset$object[[which(pset$id == x_col)]] : attempt to select
> less than one element in get1index

(Model runs in less than 20 seconds)

**Data Source:** https://www.kaggle.com/c/sliced-s01e07-HmPsw2/data?select=train.csv

**Youtube:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCGmh3NIJ7I

Would highly Appreciate any help !!

## code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(glue)
library(skimr)
library(tidymodels)

dataset <- read_csv("../Data/train.csv") %>% 
  mutate(churned = ifelse(attrition_flag == 1, "Yes","No")) %>% 
  select(-attrition_flag)

set.seed(2021)


spl <- initial_split(dataset)

train <- training(spl)
test <- testing(spl)

train_5fold <- train %>% vfold_cv(5)
```

### Modeling

```
mset <- metric_set(mn_log_loss)

control <- control_grid(save_workflow = TRUE,
                        save_pred = TRUE,
                        extract = extract_model)
```

recipe

```
xg_rec_1 <- recipe(churned ~  gender + total_trans_amt + total_trans_ct + avg_utilization_ratio + 
         total_revolving_bal + total_relationship_count + total_ct_chng_q4_q1 + credit_limit + months_inactive_12_mon,
        data = train) %>% 

  step_dummy(all_nominal_predictors())
```

```
# model specs
xg_spec <- parsnip::boost_tree(learn_rate = 0.02) %>% 
  set_engine("xgboost") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")

# workflow
xg_wf_1 <- workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(xg_rec_1) %>% 
  add_model(xg_spec)

# Model tuning
xg_res_1 <- xg_wf_1 %>% 
  tune_grid(
    resamples = train_5fold,
    metrics = mset,
    control = control,
    grid = crossing(trees = seq(20,700, 50),
    mtry = c(3,5,7)))
```

**I get Error when I try to auto plot this:**

```
autoplot(xg_res_1)
```

> Error in pset$object[[which(pset$id == x_col)]] : attempt to select
> less than one element in get1index

Where as in the **Youtube vid** he is successfully plotting with **autoplot()** at 35:02

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By adding `trees = tune(), mtry = tune(),` to boost_tree() it worked.

```
xg_spec <- parsnip::boost_tree(trees = tune(),
    mtry = tune(),
    learn_rate = 0.02) %>% 
  set_engine("xgboost") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")
```

[image]